# Windows 7 PC randomly triggers keyboard shortcuts

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

For some reason, my computer started to act up.
First, I couldn't type any of the numbers, since they'd select a program in the taskbar, and enter would bring up Windows Media.
Just a while ago, pressing the letter L would lock me out of my computer, and pressing P would bring up projection options (like extension, duplicate, etc.)
Sticky Keys was turned off both times this happened, and while pressing the Windows key a few times did work, these are showing up out of the blue, and it may happen again. I was just playing a game when suddenly I pressed a number and it went to the taskbar. And no, the game I was playing does not have viruses, since every other computer I've had the game on never had this problem. Anyone have advice on how to permanently stop this?

Answer (score 1):

One of your Win keys are stuck down. Win + L is the lock computer shortcut. Win + P is the projection options shortcut. Win + D will minimize everything etc.

Somehow one of the keys are getting stuck down, quite possibly the physical keys themselves are making contact (any spills?). You could try removing the key caps and cleaning underneath, although carefully.

Edit: To clarify which keys I'm referring to:

[image: Win key]

Comment: I had this problem too.  Still am.  Not sure the key is stuck.  Sometimes when I press it it fixes it.  Sometimes CTRL-ALT-DEL will fix it if I cancel after it.  I am using Dameware but not sure that matters (to a windows 10 machine)